# RLMMigration How to handle leaped schema versions

Tags: objective-c, realm

Assume I add a property `colorLenghtSort` in one schema update, and in the next version I rename the property to remove the typo: `colorLengthSort`.

My migration looks as follows

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.schemaVersion = 25;
config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    if(oldSchemaVersion < 24) {
        // added Hairstyle.colorLenghtSort, will be added automatically
    }
    if(oldSchemaVersion < 25) {
        // if (schema-has-property colorLenghtSort) .... <- how to get this?
        [migration renamePropertyForClass:Hairstyle.className oldName:@"colorLenghtSort" newName:@"colorLengthSort"];
    }
};
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
```

**Now**
If a user came from schemaVersion **23 or lower**, his realm does not have the (misspelled) property because he leaped V24. Then, the migration will fail :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Cannot rename property 'Hairstyle.colorLenghtSort' because it does
>   not exist.'

How can I check if the property is there?

**EDIT:** I found the solution!

```
if(oldSchemaVersion < 25) {

    RLMObjectSchema * oldhairstyleSchema = [[migration oldSchema] objectForKeyedSubscript:Hairstyle.className];
    bool renameNecessary = NO;
    for(RLMProperty * prop in oldhairstyleSchema.properties) {
        if([prop.name isEqualToString:@"colorLenghtSort"]){
            renameNecessary = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(renameNecessary)
        [migration renamePropertyForClass:Hairstyle.className oldName:@"colorLenghtSort" newName:@"colorLengthSort"];
}
```

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer (and then accept it).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
if(oldSchemaVersion < 25) {

    RLMObjectSchema * oldhairstyleSchema = [[migration oldSchema] objectForKeyedSubscript:Hairstyle.className];
    bool renameNecessary = NO;
    for(RLMProperty * prop in oldhairstyleSchema.properties) {
        if([prop.name isEqualToString:@"colorLenghtSort"]){
            renameNecessary = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(renameNecessary)
        [migration renamePropertyForClass:Hairstyle.className oldName:@"colorLenghtSort" newName:@"colorLengthSort"];
}
```